# Angular2 http.get throws EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot read property 'toString' of null

Tags: javascript, http, exception, angular, http-headers

Today I have come across an error thrown by get method of Http module of Angular2 and it took me a while to figure out the solution so I decided to put it here and make someones life less painful. Otherwise, if you like to spend hours debugging angular/core then don't read it :).

My use case is about sending GET request without body payload with jwt token set to header like this:

```js
let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
headers.append('Authorization', token);

let options = new RequestOptions({
    headers: headers
});
```

And then I was making a get request to localhost where I have server running:

```js
return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/someApiUrl', options)
    .toPromise()
    .then(this.extractData)
    .catch(this.handleError);
```

But whatever I do Angular is throwing an exception

```js
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot read property 'toString' of null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular was throwing exception because GET request was sent without a body and there is no check for `null`. So, when Angular was trying to coerce body of the request to string it was actually calling `toString()` method on `null`.

The solution is to set the body explicitly to empty string like so:

```
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers,
        body: ''
    });
```